# Recursive dictionary searching

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I'm trying to make a function that would take nested array (dict/list in any order) and a key name as arguments and return all values of that key in a list.

```
my_key = "Items"

my_dict = [{'z': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'Items': [{'Slot': 1, 'id': 'minecraft:rail', 'Count': 1}, {'Slot': 2, 'id': 'minecraft:white_shulker_box', 'tag': {'BlockEntityTag': {'id': 'minecraft:shulker_box', 'Items': [{'Slot': 0, 'Count': 1, 'tag': {'Items': [{'id': 'minecraft:amethyst_shard', 'Count': 1}]}, 'id': 'minecraft:bundle'}]}}, 'Count': 1}]}]

def recursive_lookup(data, key):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for i in data:
            recursive_lookup(i, key)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for i, v in data.items():
            if i == key:
                print(f'{v = }')
            if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict): recursive_lookup(v, key)
print(recursive_lookup(my_dict, my_key))
```

Currently it prints out found items at `print(f'{v = }')`. How can I store those in a list and pass as a function return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can what you want ***without*** any explicit recursion at all by making use of the `json` module in the standard library (assuming your data can be serialized into that format). This is because the JSON decoder supports an `object_hook` argument which is a function it will call everytime it encounters a dictionary.

The basic idea is to specify a function via this argument that merely "watches" what is being decoded and checks it for the sought-after key.

Here's what I mean:

```
import json

my_key = "Items"
my_dict = [{'z': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'Items': [{'Slot': 1, 'id': 'minecraft:rail', 'Count': 1}, {'Slot': 2, 'id': 'minecraft:white_shulker_box', 'tag': {'BlockEntityTag': {'id': 'minecraft:shulker_box', 'Items': [{'Slot': 0, 'Count': 1, 'tag': {'Items': [{'id': 'minecraft:amethyst_shard', 'Count': 1}]}, 'id': 'minecraft:bundle'}]}}, 'Count': 1}]}]

def lookup(data, key):
    results = []

    def decode_dict(a_dict):
        try:
            results.append(a_dict[key])
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return a_dict

    json_repr = json.dumps(data)  # Convert to JSON format.
    json.loads(json_repr, object_hook=decode_dict)  # Return value ignored.
    return results

from pprint import pprint
pprint(lookup(my_dict, my_key), sort_dicts=False)
```

Pretty-printed result list:

```
[[{'id': 'minecraft:amethyst_shard', 'Count': 1}],
 [{'Slot': 0,
   'Count': 1,
   'tag': {'Items': [{'id': 'minecraft:amethyst_shard', 'Count': 1}]},
   'id': 'minecraft:bundle'}],
 [{'Slot': 1, 'id': 'minecraft:rail', 'Count': 1},
  {'Slot': 2,
   'id': 'minecraft:white_shulker_box',
   'tag': {'BlockEntityTag': {'id': 'minecraft:shulker_box',
                              'Items': [{'Slot': 0,
                                         'Count': 1,
                                         'tag': {'Items': [{'id': 'minecraft:amethyst_shard',
                                                            'Count': 1}]},
                                         'id': 'minecraft:bundle'}]}},
   'Count': 1}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.extend()` to concatenate the result of recursive calls to a list.

```py
def recursive_lookup(data, key):
    values = []
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for i in data:
            values.extend(recursive_lookup(i, key))
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for i, v in data.items():
            if i == key:
                values.append(v)
            if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict):
                values.extend(recursive_lookup(v, key))
    return values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a running list:

```py
def recursive_lookup(data, key):
    lst = []
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for i in data:
            lst.append(recursive_lookup(i, key))
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for i, v in data.items():
            if i == key:
                lst.append([v])
            if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict): lst.append(recursive_lookup(v, key))
    return lst

print(recursive_lookup(data, 'Items'))
```